# Step-wise undo history for a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undo

I'm looking for help/ideas on how to implement a step-wise undo for a form. I have been able to get as far as a single undo event, but I'm stumped how to go further back.

In my [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/GX87w/4/), the user is making a list of sorts. They select their items:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="food1">Bread<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="food2">Milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="food3">Juice<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="item1">Paper<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="item2">Pencils<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="item3">Eraser<br>
```

Which appears in a box:
`<textarea id="text" rows="10" cols="25"></textarea>`

The list is generated with the following script:

```
// variable literals
foodtype = {
    food1: "Bread\n",
    food2: "Milk\n",
    food3: "Juice\n"
};

itemtype = {
    item1: "Paper\n",
    item2: "Pencils\n",
    item3: "Eraser\n"
};

// new text
var textbox = $('#text').val();
// old text to revert to
var oldtext = '';

// temporary holder for checkbox id
var choice = null;

// fill textarea with list
function filltext1() {
    if (choice !== null) {
        if (choice.indexOf('food') != -1) {
            textbox += foodtype[choice] + '';
            choice = null;
            $('#text').val(textbox);
        } else if (choice.indexOf('item') != -1) {
            textbox += itemtype[choice] + '';
            choice = null;
            $('#text').val(textbox);
        }
    }
}

// add new selection to list, unless unchecked
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        choice = $(this).attr('id');
        oldtext = textbox;
        filltext1();
    } else {
        $('#text').val(oldtext); // if unchecked, textarea = prior text
        textbox = oldtext; // reset variable to prior text
    }
});
```

The last bit brings my textbox, back one step if an item is unchecked. But, only if you uncheck the most recent selection.

An asynchronous unchecking of a box doesn't remove that item's entry - rather, just the last selection.

How would I link the initial selection to a state that can be reverted? Or put another way, is there a way to asynchronously undo the item's entry into the list? I'd even be happy with a *sequential undo* if that is all that is possible.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

After messing around a bit, I took another approach. Rather than try to undo, I instead deleted each checked item. This allows for an asynchronous removal in the list example.

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GX87w/6/).

The relevant code change is here:

```
else {
        var del = $(this).attr('id'); // set unchecked id
        if (del.indexOf('food') != -1){
            oldtext = textbox.replace(foodtype[del], '');} // delete referenced literal
        else if (del.indexOf('item') != -1){
            oldtext = textbox.replace(itemtype[del], '');} // delete referenced literal            
        textbox = oldtext; // recapture old version
        $('#text').val(oldtext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just rebuild the list. "Undo" functionality is not appropriate here because the user will not necessarily uncheck items in the same order he checked them. Your current example fails when I check Bread, check Milk, and then uncheck Bread (Milk is unexpectedly removed from the list).

```
// variable literals
var choiceMap = {
    food1: 'Bread',
    food2: 'Milk',
    food3: 'Juice',
    item1: 'Paper',
    item2: 'Pencils',
    item3: 'Eraser'
};

// Container for all the choices currently selected.
var choices = [];

// fill textarea with list
function filltext(choices) {
    var text = choices.join('\n');
    $('#text').val(text);
}

// add new selection to list, unless unchecked
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var
        choiceKey = $(this).attr('id'),
        choice = choiceMap[choiceKey],
        index;
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        choices.push(choice);
    } else {
        // ES5: index = choices.indexOf(choice);
        index = $.inArray(choice, choices);
        choices.splice(index, 1);
    }
    filltext(choices);
});
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/J23DJ/2/)

Alternatively you could search the textbox for the item you want to remove and substring it away. But then if the user were to edit the contents of the box you would be unable to find the string, or maybe you would find the wrong one (for example if you had the items "App" and "Apple", indexOf-ing the string wouldn't work, you'd have to dynamically build a regex).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="food1" Bread="Bread" value="Bread"/>Bread<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="food2" value="Milk"/>Milk<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="food3" value="Juice"/>Juice<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="item1" value="Paper"/>Paper<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="item2" value="Pencils"/>Pencils<br />
    <input type="checkbox" id="item3" value="Eraser"/>Eraser<br />
    <textarea id="text" rows="10" cols="25"></textarea>
    </form>
    <script>
      var $check=$("input");
      var $text=$('textarea');
      $check.change(function(){
         $text.val($check.map(function(){
           if(this.checked){
           return this.value;
         }}).toArray().join('\n'));
      });
    </script>
```

You should give **values** to your checkboxes.

http://embed.plnkr.co/f0YlZFGv1kE5lQurPqo5/preview